# How to get the value present in the angular tag in selenium

Tags: java, angular, selenium

How to get the text value which is not present in HTML dom, but present in UI.[image: text box present in UI]

[image: html tag for that element or angular]

Comment: The value will be on the dom, check out the other html elements around the input control, you'll find it in there somewhere.

Comment: checked everywhere ,not present in DOM

Comment: The accepted answer is not good but check prestomanifesto's answer (highest voted) for the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever it is, you can get it with `input.getAttribute("value")`. You just need to select the input.

```js
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.tagName("app-datepicker"))
                         .findElement(By.tagName("input"));
String value = input.getAttribute("value");
```

I do so. `app-datepicker` is an AngularJS component.

Comment: tried this: but returning a null value driver.findElementByXPath("//div[contains(@class,'form_input_Trader') and contains(@class,'form_meridian_date')]/input").getAttribute("value");